# asp.net core 2.1 preview 2 - signalR CORS issues and 405 on OPTIONS request

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

Using the latest versions of signalR and @aspnet/signalr I still get issues connecting. I'm fairly sure the versions are exactly the same.
I've been following the [startup project here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/). But instead I'm using an Angular 5 application. I get issues with CORS headers and more specifically the OPTIONS request returns a 405 method not allowed.

[Visual studio version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojdeg.png).

[Typescript/javascript client version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NoLE.png)

Comment: better type the code in the post instead of using a screenshot

Comment: Having the exact same issue, with the same versions.

Comment: @JohnWaters I created an issue on the github and I was told I misconfigured my CORS in my application. Please see this issue on how I solved it: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2054

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and it appeared that order matters. Make sure you've put it like this:

```
app.UseCors(...builder...)
app.UseSignalR(...routes...)
app.UseMvc(...routes...)
```