# SignalR error 405 - what does this error tell me?

Tags: asp.net

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taeIm.png)

hey guys, got an error with signalr - google didnt really so i hope this will help

Comment: With the answer below, to get help figuring out why you got the error you should post to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

405 is method not allowed: https://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html, donno why; I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to CORS.

For .NET Framework, check the following SO post:

[SignalR throws 405 error on notify/negotiate request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513572/signalr-throws-405-error-on-notify-negotiate-request)

For ASP.NET Core, check the following SO post:

[asp.net core 2.1 preview 2 - signalR CORS issues and 405 on OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860919/asp-net-core-2-1-preview-2-signalr-cors-issues-and-405-on-options-request)